# Number of homomorphisms from $D_{2n}$ to $C_n$?

Tags: group-theory

> How many homomorphisms there are from $D_{2n}$ to $C_{n}$?

Assume $ \phi :D_{2n} \to C_n$ is a group hom, then $\forall a,b \in D_{2n}$, we have $$\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(b)\phi(a)=\phi(ba)$$ as $(C_n,*)$ is an abelian group.

So my questions:

1. Can we say directly that since $D_{2n}$ is non-abelian so there is no homomorphism between the two groups?
2. If say, $a=r^is^j,b=r^ks^l$, where $r$ is rotation through ${2\pi} \over n$ and $s$ is reflection, can we prove $r^is^j=s^jr^{-i}$ and $s^jr^i=r^{-i}s^j$?

Comment: You always have the trivial homomorphism between groups (mapping everything to the neutral element). For homomorphisms to an abelian group, it is helpful to know the "commutator subgroup" of the other group. Do you know what a commutator is?

Comment: No...I suppose I could better understand if an example is given.

Comment: The commutator subgroup of $G$ (usually denoted $G'$ like in Amin's answer) is the subgroup $\langle x^{-1}y^{-1}xy | x, y\in G\rangle$ generated by all commutators $[x, y] := x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ in $G$. Your equation $\phi(ab) = \dots = \phi(ba)$ can be rewritten as $\phi(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab) = 1$, so you were on the right track. Next you should try to find all commutators in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: @j.p. The commutators form a group $<r^2>$, but I cannot proceed from there.

Comment: For all homomorphisms $\phi : D_{2n}\to C_n$ you know that $\phi(r^2) = 1$. Homomorphisms are uniquely determined by the images of a generating set. In your case $r$ and $s$ generate $D_{2n}$, so you have to find their possible images in $C_n$ and check which possible combinations $(\phi(r), \phi(s))$ can come from (=can be extended to) a group homomorphism. Observe that $\phi(r^2) = 1$ implies that $\phi(r)$ has order $1$ or $2$. (What do you know about $\langle r^2\rangle$ if $r$ has odd order?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of proof:** Let $f$ be such a homomorphism and put $G = D_{2n}$. Then by the First Isomorphism Theorem, $G / \ker f$ is a subgroup of a $C_n$. Hence  $G / \ker f$ is abelian (it is indeed cyclic). So $G'\le \ker f$. On the other hand in dihedral groups,  $G/G'$ is of order $2$ or $4$. So either $\ker f= G$ or $|G/ \ker f | = 2$. You can now handle the reminder of the proof.

Comment: what does the notation $G'$ mean?

Comment: Look at @j.p's comment. Just note that $G/K$ is abelian if and only if $G' \le K$.

Comment: @Amin: You seem to assume the convention that $D_{2n}$ is the symmetry group of the regular $(2n)$-gon, whereas Rescy_ uses the other convention that $D_{2n}$ has order $2n$ (see the definition of $r$ in 2.).

Comment: Actually the order of $G$ will influence in details, while what I suggest is rather general. The only thing I used about the properties of dihedral groups is the fact that $G/G' \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: @Amin: For $n=3$ one has $D_6 = S_3$ according to Rescy_'s convention.

Comment: Thank you,  I modified my answer. However it does not influence the result, because in general if $G / \ker f$ is cyclic then it is of order 1 or 2.

Comment: @Amin: Yes, for odd $n$ the group $C_n$ anyway doesn't contain many possible images for an element of order $2$.